# include fails if file is in another directory

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a php file that has some functions in it.
My original plan was to store it in a different directory, but when I do that, include fails.

**Here is what I mean:**

```
var_dump(file_exists("/dir/functions.php")); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(file_exists("dir/functions.php")); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(file_exists("http://www.example.com/dir/functions.php")); // also returns bool(false)
var_dump(file_exists("functions.php")); // returns bool(true) if I place the file in the same directory
var_dump(include("/dir/functions.php")); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(include("dir/functions.php")); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(function_exists(someFunction));// returns bool(false)

var_dump(include("functions.php"));// returns bool(true) if I place the file in the same directory
var_dump(function_exists(someFunction));// returns bool(true)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I checked and the files are all there, and they have read and execute permission, i.e. `755`

Comment: How about trying file_exists(dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '/dir/functions.php');

Comment: show me the structure of your directory.

Comment: Maybe, delete leading slash var_dump(file_exists("dir/functions.php")); ?

Comment: if 'dir' folder is directly next to the current file, delete the leading slash

Comment: I tried removing the leading slash but I get the same problem. The structure is this: `www.example.com/site/index.php` and `www.example.com/dir/functions.php`

Comment: `/dir/file.php` denotes an ABSOLUTE path if you are on a linux machine. if you want to include a file relative to the including php file your path must look like this `dir/file.php`

Comment: @ITroubs okay, but how come that both 
`var_dump(file_exists("dir/functions.php"));` and 
`var_dump(file_exists("/dir/functions.php"));` return `bool(false)` ??

Comment: @splash58 I edited my answer to include solution without leading slash but I have the same problem.

Comment: having the structure of your directory, the answer is: "../dir/functions.php"

Comment: halleluja... post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function include requires a full server path or a path relative to the directory where the calling script is located
Since the directory structure

```
www.example.com/site/index.php
www.example.com/dir/functions.php
```

the correct call with a relative path is

```
include("../dir/functions.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of this(your example) file? Maybe you need to do `../` or go back to root location and then making the path.

Example:

```
include('../dir/script.php');
```